# How to summation number string form SQL Server in Label

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, button

I get number in SQL Server and show in label with number:

```
1.1.2
```

I want when the button is pressed the label will be + 1.

```
Expectation result: 1.1.3
```

Bellow code I using in project:

```
private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Checkversion();
        }

public void Checkversion()
        {
            string maincon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connstring"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(maincon);
            string sqlquery = ("select * from tbl_Version ");
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            {
                sqlconn.Open();
                da.SelectCommand = sqlcomm;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                serverVersion = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Version"].ToString();
                lbVerionUpdate.Text = serverVersion;
                sqlconn.Close();
            }
        }
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(lbVerionUpdate.Text);
            i++;
            var version = i.ToString();
            lbVerionUpdate.Text = version;
        }
```

I know, if it is integer then ok, but the result is decimal so the program gives error:
**System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'**

I tried replacing from *int* to *float* but same result, Please help me fix it or provide alternative solution. Thanks

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968420/increment-version-number-in-c-sharp-code)

Comment: Problem solved, Thanks for support @jarlh

Comment: You have a bunch of side issues with your code. You need `using` blocks on all SQL objects. Don't `select *`, specify only the exact columns you need. You don't need a `DataSet` or `DataAdapter, just use `DataTable.Load`. If you only want one column, one row, then use `ExecuteScalar`

Answer (score 1):

The text "1.1.2" is not a number (not an integer, not a decimal too) threre is 2 points !

You can split text, convert the last entry of the array into an integer, increment it  and then concat the array.

Like

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbVerionUpdate.Text = IncremVersion(lbVerionUpdate.Text);
    }

    private string IncremVersion(string version)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(version))
        {
            var nfos = version.Split('.');
            if (nfos != null && nfos.Length > 0)
            {
                string revisionTxt = nfos[nfos.Length - 1];
                if (int.TryParse(revisionTxt, out int revision))
                {
                    revisionTxt = (revision++).ToString();
                }

                nfos[nfos.Length - 1] = revisionTxt;
                return string.Join('.', nfos);
            }
        }

        // Fail to increment Version here !
        return version
    }
```

Comment: return string.Join('.', nfos); cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'

Comment: Sorry : replace string.Join('.', nfos); BY string.Join(**"."**, nfos); it would be better

Answer (score 1):

The problem is now solved thanks to [@jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh).

I use the following code.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string _versionDB = lbVerionUpdate.Text;
    var version = new Version(_versionDB);
    var newRevisionVersion = new Version(version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build + 1);
    _versionDB = newRevisionVersion.ToString();
    lbVerionUpdate.Text = _versionDB;
}
```